# Use $filter query parameter on /groups/{id}/members with Graph API for Azure B2C Tenant

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

Performing the [following HTTP request to the Microsoft Graph API:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-5-use-filter-to-get-group-membership-with-a-display-name-that-starts-with-the-letter-a-including-a-count-of-returned-objects)

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/members?$count=true&$filter=startswith(displayName, 'a')
ConsistencyLevel: eventual
```

Results in the following response when querying users for an Azure B2C tenant:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code":"Request_UnsupportedQuery",
        "message":"The specified filter to the reference property query is currently not supported.",
        "innerError":{
            "date":"2022-12-11T18:02:40",
            "request-id":"50ddfd29-3937-4bff-b84e-121a33149996",
            "client-request-id":"50ddfd29-3937-4bff-b84e-121a33149996"
        }
    }
}
```

According to [this Microsoft documentation article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http), the $count query parameter and the ConsistencyLevel header and $count are referred to as advanced query parameters. According to the same article, the advanced query capabilities are currently not available for Azure AD B2C tenants.

My question is how can I use $filter and perform other queries on members of a group using the MS Graph API on an Azure B2C tenant?

I can perform the same query on the /users endpoint with no issue, because it does not require the ConsistencyLevel header or the $count query parameter.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

When I ran the same query in Azure AD Tenant, I got the results successfully:

[image]

> **Note** that: **`$count`** parameter is currently not available in Azure AD B2C tenants and the advance query you are trying to achieve is also not supported as Azure AD B2C doesn't support group management.

You can get the members of the Azure AD B2C Group by running the below query:

```
GET
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/GroupID/members?$select=displayName
```

[image]

Comment: The question is how to use filtering in Azure AD B2C. You provided query without $filter parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm glad you were able to reproduce my problem. I need to be able to $filter in a B2C tenant or find a valid workaround

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Graph allows you to manage resources in your Azure AD B2C directory. The following Microsoft Graph API operations are supported for the management of Azure AD B2C resources, including users, identity providers, user flows, custom policies, and policy keys. Each link in the following sections targets the corresponding page within the Microsoft Graph API reference for that operation.

There is no supportability for group management in Azure AD B2C , please check the [list of supportability.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-operations)

**Screenshot 1**

[image]

As you said the same query in /users endpoint worked , because its supported and doesn't required ConsistencyLevel header .You can see the list to query for  users endpoint (Screenshot 1).

Hope this will helps

Thanks

Comment: I stated all this information in my question. I need to be able to $filter in a B2C tenant or at least find a suitable workaround to do so. Any insight on how to do that would be appreciated